# After installing Python 64 bit on my 64 bit machine but it is still showing python 32

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, 64-bit

I have installed the latest version of Python 64 bit on my 64-bit machine but it is still showing python 32. I can't install Tensorflow. Can anyone help?

[image: System]

[image: Installers]

[image: Python Commnd-Line]

[image: Add remove Program]

Comment: Please provide a filtered view of `Python` within Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: Research ‘‘PATH variable’’.

Comment: @Ramhound I have added the screenshot, it is showing both versions are installed, so why can't I install tensorflow??

Comment: @Scott Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Uninstall the 32-bit version of Python and reinstall the 64-bit version of Python.

Comment: @Aaqib - The 32-bit version of Python is being detected before the 32-bit version.  Having both versions installed serves no purpose unless you specifically need the 32-bit version installed (due to an incompatibility with the 64-bit version)

Comment: @Aaqib - Specific information with regards the error you receive would be required to ask that entirely different question.  The reason 32-bit version of Python is being detected is due to the PATH system variable contains the path to the 32-bit version before the 64-bit version.  “I can’t install Tensorflow” isn’t detailed enough to answer the underline question of the “why can’t I install Tensorflow”.  You need to provide specific details.

Comment: Regarding `PATH`: see, for example, the comments on [How to add and configure JDK 11 on Linux Mint 19](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/507824/23408).